# Помогите приложение падает если включен (minifyEnabled true ) Нужно написать исключение

Tags: java, android

Приложение падает если включен  (minifyEnabled  true )  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError .Такое началось после Migrate to android x .
Мне посоветовали написать исключение в ProGuard но я там нечего не понимаю очень нужно убрать ошибку . Все работает по умолчанию никаких исключений я до этого не писал .

Хотелось -бы уточнить библиотеки я обновил после перехода на Migrate to android x 
а вылетать начало до .(Это на случай если библиотеки альфа или бета версии)

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.loadDrawableFromDelegates (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.addDelegate (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .addDrawableToCache (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .addTintListToCache (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .createCacheKey (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .createTintFilter (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .get (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .getCachedDrawable (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .getDrawable (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .getPorterDuffColorFilter (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .getTintMode (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .installDefaultInflateDelegates (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .isVectorDrawable (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .onConfigurationChanged (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .onDrawableLoadedFromResources (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .setHooks (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .tintDrawable (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .tintDrawableUsingColorFilter (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.addDelegate (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .addDrawableToCache (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .addTintListToCache (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .createCacheKey (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .createTintFilter (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .get (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .getCachedDrawable (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .getDrawable (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .getPorterDuffColorFilter (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .getTintMode (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .installDefaultInflateDelegates (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .isVectorDrawable (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .onConfigurationChanged (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .onDrawableLoadedFromResources (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .setHooks (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .tintDrawable (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .tintDrawableUsingColorFilter (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.checkVectorDrawableSetup (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .getTintList (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.addDelegate (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .addDrawableToCache (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .addTintListToCache (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .createCacheKey (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .createTintFilter (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .get (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .getCachedDrawable (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .getDrawable (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .getPorterDuffColorFilter (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .getTintMode (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .installDefaultInflateDelegates (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .isVectorDrawable (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .onConfigurationChanged (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .onDrawableLoadedFromResources (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .setHooks (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .tintDrawable (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  or                     .tintDrawableUsingColorFilter (ResourceManagerInternal.java)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.access$000 (AppCompatDrawableManager.java)
  or                     .getDrawable (AppCompatDrawableManager.java)
  or                     .getPorterDuffColorFilter (AppCompatDrawableManager.java)
  or                     .onConfigurationChanged (AppCompatDrawableManager.java)
  or                     .tintDrawable (AppCompatDrawableManager.java)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.TintTypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize (TintTypedArray.java)
  or                     .getDrawableIfKnown (TintTypedArray.java)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.addContentView (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .applyDayNight (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .attachBaseContext (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .attachToWindow (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .callOnPanelClosed (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .closePanel (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .createView (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .dispatchKeyEvent (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .findMenuPanel (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .findViewById (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .getPanelState (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .initializePanelContent (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .onConfigurationChanged (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .onCreate (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .onKeyDown (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .onMenuItemSelected (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .onMenuModeChange (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .onSubDecorInstalled (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .openPanel (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .performPanelShortcut (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .reopenMenu (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .setContentView (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .setTitle (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .shouldInheritContext (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  or                     .startSupportActionMode (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate (AppCompatActivity.java)
  at dima113xxx.coin_calculator.Main2Activity.onCreate (Main2Activity.java)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6876)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3206)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3349)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100 (ActivityThread.java:221)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1794)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:158)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7225)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1230)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

/// Вот мои библиотеки

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "dima113xxx.coin_calculator"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 66
        versionName "4.4.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled  true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0-alpha02', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:18.1.1'
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
}




apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Я как-то подозреваю, что проблемы у вас из-за использования альфа-, бета-версий библиотек. Лучше использовать стабильные. Ещё попробуйте заменить `'proguard-android.txt'` на `'proguard-android-optimize.txt'` - сейчас в новых проектах студия прописывает его.

Comment: Хотелось -бы уточнить библиотеки я обновил после перехода на  Migrate to android x .К сожалению  'proguard-android-optimize.txt' не работает.